# Civi Volunteer 2.4.1 fatal errors on install CiviCRM 5.33.2 Drupal 7.78

Tags: civivolunteer

I have just installed Civi Volunteer on Civi 5.33.2 with Drupal 7.78.  No errors were displayed on install.  I am seeing errors, including fatal ones.  I have worked through the Volunteers menu items and found the following:
New Volunteer Project
CiviVolunteer and nothing else

Manage Volunteer Projects
relationship_type_id is not a valid integer

Configure Roles
Working

Configure Project Relationships
getFieldValue failed

Configure volunteer Settings
'volunteer_project_relationship' is not a valid option for field option_group_id

Volunteer Interest Form
Form displays

Search for Volunteer Opportunities
Form working

I followed the various advices, including uninstall and reinstall, running the job to remove the tables, removing the extension files, clearing caches and resetting paths. I have a log file of the errors. I am not sure how to include this.

Any help would be most welcome, as I am trying to persuade a possible new user with some 80 volunteers to take CiviCRM.

Regards
Graham

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm seeing that the only issue is the option group for volunteer_project_relationship did not get created.

If this is just a demo,it might be fine to create the option group manually. I would worry about what else failed if this is a permanent setup.

The install step in question is in the Upgrader.php file in installProjectRelationships(). You can see it is calling  `civicrm_api3('OptionGroup', 'create'...`  and `civicrm_api3('OptionValue', 'create'...`.

Try going to Administer > System Settings > Option Groups. and create the option group with the settings in the installer.

You can then visit Volunteer > Configure Project Relationships to add the OptionValues. Again, look to Upgrader.php for the defaults.

If you want to get to the root of the matter, I would confirm that all available logging and debugging is enabled and try the install from the ground up. If it still persists with a fresh install of Civi, I would try some other recent releases to see if there really is an incompatibility introduced in the CiviCRM release.

Let me know if you would like to chat about the suitability of CiviVolunteer for the organization you are creating this demo for.

Cheers

Comment: Michael.  Thank you very much for coming back so quickly.  I have done as you suggested and it now works fine.  I will carry out a clean install to see if this repeats.  I would love to chat about the use of Civi Volunteer.  Do you want to have a Zoom call ?I have an account, which will give us 40 minutes.  I am in the UK.  Regards Graham

Comment: Great! Do please let me knnow if you replicate the problem. A github issue is probably more appropriate in that case.

My week has gotten full. Would Tuesday at 15:00 UTC or later work for you? (I'm in Washingon, DC). I'm pretty available Tues-Thurs next week. You can send the zoom invite to ginkgomzd <at> fastmail.com

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for coming back.  I have just sent you a link to the meeting at 3 pm on Tuesday.  Have a good weekend.

Comment: ..wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/org.civicrm.volunteer/CRM/Volunteer/Upgrader.php

Comment: No volunteer_project_relationship - clean install. Does Upgrader.php run on a clean install? I don't see any other api call?